# User defined placement of Legend in 3D graphics

Tags: legending

> I am trying to position the legend in a 3D graphics using PlotLegend[Placed...
> If I do this, I am not able to rotate the 3D graphics. The default legend location is a little too far from the graphics box, so I want to place it differently. Is there someway of doing this while preserving the rotation viewing function?<

```
list1 = {2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1, 5};
list2 = {3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 4};

data1 = {{250, 0.0001`, 0.17`}, {276, 0.000085`, 0.17`}, {381, 
0.000094`, 0.13`}, {306, 0.000072`, 0.14`}, {310, 0.00005`, 
0.1`}, {283, 0.00011`, 0.16`}, {291, 0.00008`, 0.23`}}
data2 = {{123, 0.00061`, 0.25`}, {130, 0.000055`, 0.046`}, {90, 
0.00071`, 0.27`}, {115, 0.00012`, 0.26`}, {103, 0.00032`, 
0.48`}, {109, 0.0012`, 0.24`}, {101, 0.00063`, 0.28`}}
testplot = 
ListPointPlot3D[{data1 -> list1, data2 -> list2}, 
PlotRange -> {{80, 400.}, {0, .0015}, {0, .8}}, 
PlotStyle -> (Directive[PointSize[.02], Opacity[2.8], 
   AbsoluteThickness[3.0], #] & /@ {Hue[0.58, 1, 1], 
  Hue[0., 1, 1], Hue[0.58, 1, 1], Hue[1., 1, .0], 
  Hue[0.8, .8, .5], Hue[1., 0.5, 1.]}), 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontSize -> 12, FontColor -> Black], 
 PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[{"data1 ", "data2"}, LegendLabel -> " ", 
 LabelStyle -> {Helvetica, Bold, 12}], {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
 AxesLabel -> {" xtest name", "y testname", 
 Rotate["ztestname", Pi/2]}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["", FontSize -> 12, FontColor -> Black], 
 FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
 ViewAngle -> 30*Degree]
 test3d = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.2], Blue, 
 InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, .21}, {0, 1, .21}, {0, 0, .21}}]}]
Show[testplot, test3d, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) to add the legend as a label:

```
Labeled[Show[testplot[[1]], test3d, SphericalRegion -> True], testplot[[2, 1]], 
 {{Top, Right}}, 
 FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, -100}}]
```

[image]

**Note:** The first part of `testplot` (that is, `testplot[[1]]`) contains the 3D graphics object and the second part contains the legend wrapped in `Placed`:

```
testplot[[2]]
```

[image]